# how to clean up /root folder in EC2 linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

One of my AWS EC2 Instance is occupying over 222 GB. But surprisingly when I check inside the /root folder, I just found one file which is of 5MB in size. I am not sure how to clear the disk space and how to find all those hidden files, which are taking 222 GB of disk space.

when I this command - `du -shx /*` : This is the output I got -

```
0       /bin
88M     /boot
0       /dev
31M     /etc
86M     /home
0       /lib
0       /lib64
0       /local
0       /media
0       /mnt
2.2G    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7699/task/7699/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7699/task/7699/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7699/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7699/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7828’: No such file or directory
0       /proc
222G    /root
1.7M    /run
0       /sbin
0       /srv
0       /sys
0       /tmp
3.1G    /usr
5.7G    /var
```

How to clear the /root folder? when I run this command : `du -shx /root/*`, I just found a 5MB file but it is taking 222 GB of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem , but instead with my home partition .

I resorted to something more visually representing the size of each sub-directory like [dutree](https://github.com/nachoparker/dutree) by running the command  `dutree -s` with the -s flag to get more minimal result at the choosen directory .

Answer (score 0):

You can use ncdu: This piece of software scans whatever directory you want and lets you browse through it, listing the current sizes of files/folders.

If it's not installed:

apt install ncdu

Afterwards: ncdu -rx /

This will scan recursively everything from the root (not to confuse with the folder /root). You then can navigate your file system and check what takes away the space.

Answer (score 0):

The command `du -shx /root/*` will look at all files in that folder that match the `*` glob -- by default, that excludes hidden files and directories.

You can either use `shopt -s dotglob` to change the globbing behaviour, or explicitly list `/root/.*` in the list of paths. The latter is likely to have fewer surprising effects.